# "I wish I knew where you are" - is this sentence idiomatic?

Tags: grammar, wish

If the speaker doesn't know where another person is, but they wish they did know, would the following sentence be a good way to express this wish?

> I wish I knew where you are now.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: I really wonder why people downrate such questions. I don't see anything wrong with this question. I'm surprised at what might drive people to dislike such a question. You need to understand that the concepts of different languages are different, so as a result, many questions may arise in people's minds to ask.

Comment: Clear lack of research is often a reason for downvotes and close votes.

Comment: If you type `"I wish I knew" grammar` into Google, the first results are lots of questions on this site.

Comment: Is your question about the difference between "I wish I knew" and "I wish I'd known"  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252519/i-wish-i-knew-i-wish-i-had-known

Comment: Shahrooz, "Is this correct?" questions are off-topic. I assume you mean "Is it OK to use the present tense _where you are_ with the past tense _knew_?". Yes, it is.

Comment: It is OK, but it would be more natural to say "I wish I knew where you **were** now", which uses the modal preterite form "were". The "now" marks it clearly as being current time.

Comment: @mihcael harvey Thank for your clarification, But I take the liberty to disagree with your reasoning ,as grammar references fail to satisfy the questions rise from the learners' mind. [Be good].

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, the speaker doesn't currently know where the other person is, but they are engaged in the process of wishing that they knew where the other person is.

> "I wish I knew where you are"

"Knew" is not actually indicating the past here, as indicated by "I wish" and "are." It is correct if used in the way that you described. This is a non-obvious and good question.

Note: BillJ pointed out that "I wish I knew where you were" is more natural, and I think this is correct for someone's current location. However, I think that "I wish I knew where you were" requires context to not be interpreted as someone's past location.

See examples here: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+wish+I+knew+where+you+are%22

Comment: "I wish I knew where you were now", using the modal preterite form "were", is more natural. The "now" marks it as a current situation.

Comment: @BillJ I can't think of a way for that to work in a situation where someone wants to know the current location of another person. "Were" implies we currently want to know about the past, not current, location of a person.

Comment: Read my comment again: I clearly said that the **"now"** marks it as a current situation, But even without such a marker, context would clarify the temporal location. Consider: Someone's kid rings home to say that they are staying at a secret location, and mum says "Well OK, but I wish I knew where you were". A perfectly normal response about current time.

Comment: @BillJ Right. Okay, I definitely see that. Were works.